# Magento 2.3.5 - Configurable product showing all associate product in configuration grid in admin

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, product-grid, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I'm facing an issue that when I open any configurable product and then in configuration grid of associate products when I click on next to get another list of associate products its load all the products even if I have per page size set to 20 products.

[image]

Please help me if anyone knows how to fix this issue.